Nestjs formdata streaming
Basically I have an external api for campaign update. Each campaign contains a image. That API expects image as file from my end. (jps,jpeg,svg,png,GIF format). I already did post api and its working fine. but in my update api its being success but values are not changing. here I am attaching my code.
Controller:
@Put(':id')
  @ApiFile('image')
  @ApiBody({ type: UpdateCampaignDto })
  async update(
    @UploadedFile() image: Express.Multer.File,
    @Param('id') id: string,
    @Body() updateCampaignDto: UpdateCampaignDto,
  ) {
    try {
      const payload = await this.campaignService.update(+id, updateCampaignDto,image);
      return { message: 'Campaign Updated successfully!', payload };
    } catch (error) {
      throw new BadRequestException('Error updating campaign');
    }
  }

Service:
async update(id: number, updateCampaignDto: UpdateCampaignDto, image: Express.Multer.File) {
    const formData = new FormData();

    if (image) {
      const imageStream = streamifier.createReadStream(image.buffer);
      formData.append('image_url', imageStream, {
        filename: image.originalname,
        contentType: image.mimetype,
      });
    }    

    for (const key in updateCampaignDto) {
      let value = updateCampaignDto[key];

      if (key === 'start_date' || key === 'end_date') {
        value = moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD');
      }

      if (Array.isArray(value)) {
        value.forEach((item) => {
          formData.append(`${key}[]`, item.toString());
        });
      } 
      else if (typeof value === 'object' && value !== null) {
        formData.append(key, JSON.stringify(value));
      } 
      else {
        formData.append(key, value.toString());
      }
    }

    const url = `${process.env.COUPON_URL}/api/v1/campaigns/${id}`;
    const authenticateResponse = await this.authenticate();

    try {
      const response = await axios.put(
        url,
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            Accept: 'application/json',
            Authorization: `Bearer ${authenticateResponse.access_token}`,
            ...formData.getHeaders(), 
          },
        },
      );

      return response.data;
    } catch (error) {
      throw new Error('Failed to update campaign');
    }
  }

This api is working without formdata.
